# How to Deploy Node app to Heroku (H10 ERROR503)

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern

My code works fine through localhost, but whenever I attempt to deploy it to heroku through github connection in the 'master' branch, I receive the following errors in the heroku logs.

```
2021-02-13T22:35:46.729719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-02-13T22:35:46.729909+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chatapp@1.0.0 start script.
2021-02-13T22:35:46.730061+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-02-13T22:35:46.738214+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-13T22:35:46.738412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-13T22:35:46.738508+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-13T22_35_46_731Z-debug.log
2021-02-13T22:35:46.798677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-13T22:35:46.861218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-13T22:35:48.208652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ichat33.herokuapp.com request_id=0c17e270-7fcc-4bab-9b7a-f22762e71c1e fwd="70.73.177.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-13T22:35:48.714796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ichat33.herokuapp.com request_id=487c5682-f215-4732-a524-2de3d78b403f fwd="70.73.177.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-13T22:48:30.923624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ichat33.herokuapp.com request_id=c95e0aff-37aa-4512-9427-72b6d1d8dc32 fwd="70.73.177.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-13T22:48:31.378340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ichat33.herokuapp.com request_id=26c4dea3-e909-4b12-a841-c0e1ac21de46 fwd="70.73.177.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any tips or answers are greatly appreciated!

Create .env file in client and server

Comment: did you read the log file? What did it tell you?

Comment: Where would i go to access  /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-13T23_08_35_367Z-debug.log?

Comment: you go to your heroku app on herokuapp.com, then in the upper right click "more" and then run a console into your dyno, then `cat` or `nano` or etc. etc. that log file. Or you use the heroku CLI to ssh into your dyno locally and then do the same.

Comment: I entered cat in the heroku run "blank" and it opened a console that will just copy whatever i enter into it. I am also unsure how to etc the log file here

Comment: inside the console, run the following command: `cat /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-13T22_35_46_731Z-debug.log` . That should output the logs.

Comment: I get "cat: /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-13T23_08_35_367Z-debug.log:No such file or directory"